# Powershell: Attempting to update all sAMAccountNames in an OU; nothing past the initial "if" is working

Tags: powershell, if-statement, active-directory, try-catch

Due to some recent changes in organizational standards, I'm having to update the sAMAccountName of every user in my location's Users OU. I've written and run the code, testing it against my own account several times, but have run into consistent issues with the else, Write-Host, and Export-CSV commands.

```
$OU = 'users ou'

$users = Get-ADObject -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties sn,givenName,userPrincipalName,sAMAccountName,employeeType

$newPre2K = ''

$memberName = ''

foreach($user in $users)
{
    $memberName = $user.sn + ", " + $user.givenName
    $newPre2K = (($user.userPrincipalName).Split(".")[0]) + $user.employeeType
    Try
    {        
        if($user.sAMAccountName -ne $newPre2K)
        {
            $user.sAMAccountName = $newPre2K
            Set-ADObject -Instance $user 
            Write-Host $memberName + ": sAMAccountName change successful." -ForegroundColor Green | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Users\(me)\Desktop\sAMAccUpdate.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host $memberName + ": Member sAMAccountName has already been updated." -ForegroundColor Yellow | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Users\(me)\Desktop\sAMAccUpdate.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host $memberName + ": Unknown Error. Review CSV to identify failed changes and attempt to remediate." -ForegroundColor Red | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Users\(me)\Desktop\sAMAccUpdate.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```

The initial `if` statement functions exactly as I want it to, as does the `Write-Host`. However, the `Export-CSV` afterwards, while it does at least create the CSV file, does not put anything in it. Additionally, even after running it several times in a row, which would basically force an "else" result as my sAMAccountName was already updated and therefore doesn't fulfill the `-ne` argument in the `if` statement, I don't get any output from `Write-Host`, and nothing goes into the CSV—though it does create it if it doesn't already exist.

I've tried changing the else statement to `elseif($user.sAMAccountName -eq $newPre2K)`, and the result is the same: nothing from `Write-Host`, nothing in the CSV. I've tried both altogether removing the `Try...Catch` as well as placing it within the initial `if` and still nothing changes. I've tried swapping `Write-Host/Export-CSV` with `Write-Output/Out-File`, and that also gives me nothing.

If anyone could help me figure out the probably very obvious mistake I'm making, for both the `else/elseif` statement as well as the `Write-Host/Export-CSV` piece, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `Write-Host` does not output to the success stream by default. Therefore, nothing gets piped to `Export-Csv`.

Comment: Your error is here `$user.sAMAccountName = $newPre2K`. Try this `Set-ADUser -Identity $user -SamAccountName $newPre2K`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon see the answer I posted; the code works entirely as I intended for it to; the reason the `else` statement "wasn't working" was purely user error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will get a `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException` exception by trying `$user.sAMAccountName = $newPre2K` but suit yourself.

Comment: Negative. When I say the code works as intended, I do mean that it functions. So long as I'm not sabotaging myself, that is. Out of curiosity, though, what would make that error occur? Is this a guess on your part or did you try to do something similar yourself and were given that error?

Comment: Figured I'd give your solution a shot just because why not, not gonna turn down alternate suggestions. Those were the only times in all my tests that I ended up hitting the `Catch`, and it's done so every time I've tried it. Not sure what the issue there is, my `Catch` doesn't output the actual error that causes it, but it's not that important at the end of the day seeing as my solution works.

Comment: Why the use of `Get-ADObject` if you want users and not `Get-ADUser` ?

Comment: @Theo I ended up doing some testing with that, as in a different but overall related script I do use `Get-ADUser`. However, for whatever reason, it never quite seemed to work. Doing `Get-ADUser` instead of `Get-ADObject` sends me right to the `Catch` every time. As always, I'm sure there's some simple reason that that's happening, but I don't know what it is, and it's not that big of a deal since `Get-ADObject` works just fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I was right, it was something really obvious I was missing.

When I was testing the code against my own account, I was specifying myself in the `-Filter` argument of `$users = Get-ADObject -Filter * ...`. However, the reason the `else` statement "wasn't working" was purely because I wasn't changing my sAMAccountName in the argument to reflect the fact that it had been changed, so it was looking for an object that just didn't exist. Obviously a program can't tell you whether something has been changed already or not if the thing you're specifically telling it to look for no longer exists.

As for the `Write-Host/Export-CSV` piece, I just did it again with `Write-Output/Out-File` and it works now. It didn't before, so I must have been mucking something up, but I'm unsure what.